# Distributing cabal sandboxes

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a program that uses GHC-API to work with Haskell source files. The source files import modules from specific cabal-packages, which means that the cabal packages must be installed to the system where my program is ran.

What is the easiest way to distribute my program? I would not like to install ghc on each target system. Can I, for example, make some kind of portable a cabal sandbox that I could distribute with my program? How? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your program uses GHC-API you will need GHC anyway.You should provide your application as executable, something like that:

```
$ ghc -O2 --make -static -optc-static -optl-static A.hs -fvia-C -optl-pthread
```

or use new Cabal feature called "[Relocatable packages](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/462#issuecomment-64679257)" with key `--enable-relocatable` to provide all additional files, but it will be huge distribution, I think.